# How to merge Ruby hashes

Tags: ruby, hashmap

How can I merge these two hashes:

```
{:car => {:color => "red"}}
{:car => {:speed => "100mph"}}
```

To get:

```
{:car => {:color => "red", :speed => "100mph"}}
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

There is a [`Hash#merge`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-merge) method:

```
ruby-1.9.2 > a = {:car => {:color => "red"}}
 => {:car=>{:color=>"red"}} 
ruby-1.9.2 > b = {:car => {:speed => "100mph"}}
 => {:car=>{:speed=>"100mph"}} 
ruby-1.9.2 > a.merge(b) {|key, a_val, b_val| a_val.merge b_val }
 => {:car=>{:color=>"red", :speed=>"100mph"}}
```

You can create a recursive method if you need to merge nested hashes:

```
def merge_recursively(a, b)
  a.merge(b) {|key, a_item, b_item| merge_recursively(a_item, b_item) }
end

ruby-1.9.2 > merge_recursively(a,b)
 => {:car=>{:color=>"red", :speed=>"100mph"}}
```

Comment: yes I thought that recursively will be a part of the solution, it's exactly what I need. Thanks for you help Alex

Comment: Use `a.merge!(b)` if you want to change `a` directly.

Comment: maybe will help someone, if a_item is not a hash then above will fail i guess, something like this could help, it will overwrite all values in 'a' that you have specified in 'b', for instance your 'a' has some defaults and 'b' some actual runtime values.  def merge_recursively(a, b)
  a.merge!(b) {|key, a_item, b_item| if a_item.is_a?(Hash)
                                       merge_recursively(a_item, b_item)
                                     else b_item end }
end

Answer (score 48):

[`Hash#deep_merge`](https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/deep_merge)

**Rails 3.0+**

```
a = {:car => {:color => "red"}}
b = {:car => {:speed => "100mph"}}
a.deep_merge(b)
=> {:car=>{:color=>"red", :speed=>"100mph"}}
```

Source: https://speakerdeck.com/u/jeg2/p/10-things-you-didnt-know-rails-could-do
Slide 24

Also,

http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/Hash/deep_merge

Comment: Use `require 'active_support/core_ext/hash/deep_merge'` to pull this in if you're not using Rails.

Answer (score 21):

You can use the `merge` method defined in the ruby library. https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge

---

### **Example**

```
h1={"a"=>1,"b"=>2} 
h2={"b"=>3,"c"=>3} 
h1.merge!(h2)
```

It will give you output like this `{"a"=>1,"b"=>3,"c"=>3}`

`Merge` method does not allow duplicate key, so key b will be overwritten from ***2 to 3***.

To overcome the above problem, you can hack `merge` method like this.

```
h1.merge(h2){|k,v1,v2|[v1,v2]}
```

The above code snippet will be give you output

```
{"a"=>1,"b"=>[2,3],"c"=>3}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
h1 = {:car => {:color => "red"}}
h2 = {:car => {:speed => "100mph"}}
h3 = h1[:car].merge(h2[:car])
h4 = {:car => h3}
```

Comment: Oh, sorry, it is not quite correct ... I have updated my post