# rails/ruby merge two hashes with same key, different values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, merge

I have two hashes that I would like to merge. they look like this:

```
[{"Hello"->"3"},{"Hi"->"43"},{"Hola"->"43"}]
```

and the second hash looks like:

```
[{"Hello"->"4"},{"Hi"->"2"},{"Bonjour"->"2"}]
```

I would like to merge these two hash arrays so that the result looks like:

```
[{"Hello"->[{value1=>3},{value2=>4}],{"Hi"->[{value1=>43},{value2=>2}]},{"Bonjour"->[{value1=>0},{value2=>2}]},{"Hola"->[{value1=>43},{value2=>0}]]
```

Is there a simple way to merge these two hashes or do I have to iterate through the hashes individually and find that key in the other hash?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8415240/merge-ruby-hash)

Comment: This isn't exactly what you want, but you could try using `group_by`: `{"Hello"=>[{"Hello"=>"3"}, {"Hello"=>"4"}], "Hi"=>[{"Hi"=>"43"}, {"Hi"=>"2"}], "Hola"=>[{"Hola"=>"43"}], "Bonjour"=>[{"Bonjour"=>"2"}]}`

Comment: What are `value1` and `value2`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way is turn the arrays of hashes to hashes:

```
h1 = a1.reduce(&:merge)
# => {"Hello"=>"3", "Hi"=>"43", "Hola"=>"43"}
h2 = a2.reduce(&:merge)
# => {"Hello"=>"4", "Hi"=>"2", "Bonjour"=>"2"}
```

Then you need to find all the keys:

```
 keys = [h1, h2].flat_map(&:keys).uniq
 # => ["Hello", "Hi", "Hola", "Bonjour"]
```

Next, for each key, build the array of values:

```
keys.map do |k| 
  {k => [{value1: h1[k] || "0"}, 
         {value2: h2[k] || "0"}]}
end
# => [{"Hello"=>[{:value1=>"3"}, {:value2=>"4"}]}, 
#     {"Hi"=>[{:value1=>"43"}, {:value2=>"2"}]}, 
#     {"Hola"=>[{:value1=>"43"}, {:value2=>"0"}]}, 
#     {"Bonjour"=>[{:value1=>"0"}, {:value2=>"2"}]}]
```