# Ruby: Merge Hash containing Arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, merge

I am trying to merge two Hashes.I got the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8415240/merge-ruby-hash). As you can see I want to add one more hobby to my list. 
There are many hobbies. When h1 is formed ,only one hobby was available. When the second hobby arrived I wanted to merge it with the previous hash.

The structure of the Hashes are :

```
h1 = {"students"=>[{"name"=>"bobby", "hobbies"=>[{"outdoor"=>"cycling"}]}]}

h2 = {"students"=>[{"name"=>"bobby", "hobbies"=>[{"indoor"=>"reading"}]}]}
```

I ran this code:

```
res = h1.merge(h2) {|key,val1,val2| val1.merge val2}
```

The error I got was:

```
 undefined method `merge' for [{"name"=>"bobby", "hobbies"=>[{"outdoor"=>"cycling"}]}]:Array (NoMethodError)
```

So since array is involved, I don't know what to do. Any Help.

Required Output:

```
{"students"=>[{"name"=>"bobby", "hobbies"=>[{"outdoor"=>"cycling", "indoor"=>"reading"}]}]}
```

Comment: "pretty clear"? No, the hash would have been pretty clear if you wrote `h1 = {"students"=>[{"name"=>"bobby", "hobbies"=>[{"outdoor"=>"cycling"}]}]}`. Also, we don't know what you *want* to do. What do you want to happen when there are arrays present? Give the output example as well as input examples.

Comment: What’s the reason of storing _hobbies_ as an array consisting of one hash element?

Comment: @mudasobwa. There are many hobbies. When h1 is formed ,only one hobby was available. When the second hobby arrived I wanted to merge it with the previous hash.

Comment: That explains why you do have hash there. It’s still unclear, why you decided to wrap hobbies hash in array.

Comment: I just updated my answer to be working with many students.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer on your question might be:

```
h1.merge(h2) { |k, v1, v2| 
  v1.map.with_index { |v1e, idx| 
    v1e['hobbies'].first.merge! v2[idx]['hobbies'].first
    v1e  
  }
  v1 
}

#⇒ {
#  "students" => [
#    [0] {
#      "hobbies" => [
#        [0] {
#           "indoor" => "reading",
#          "outdoor" => "cycling"
#        }
#      ],
#         "name" => "bobby"
#    }
#  ]
# }
```

But I would definitely redesign *hobbies* to be a hash, not an array of hashes, eliminating weird `first` calls:

```
v1e['hobbies'].merge! v2[idx]['hobbies']
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Reality check , the actual Hash is very different and has technical names. For the sake of understanding, i tried to give it meaningful names.

This works! But I can't understand what you wanted those variables to mean - |vle,idx|

Comment: `v1`, `v2` stay for _value1_, _value2_. `v1e` stays for _value1_element_. `idx` is apparetnly an _index_.

Answer (score 4):

The built-in marge method cannot do what you want.
You should write the original code to merge these structure like this.

```
def recursive_merge(h1, h2)
   case h1
   when Hash
      (h1.keys + h2.keys).each do |key|
         if h1.include?(key) && h2.include?(key) then
            recursive_merge(h1[key], h2[key])
         elsif h2.include?(key)
            h1[key] = h2[key]
         end
      end
   when Array
      for i in 0...([h1.count, h2.count].max)
         if i < h1.count && i < h2.count then
            recursive_merge(h1[i], h2[i])
         elsif i < h2.count then
            h1[i] = h2[i]
         end
      end
   end
end

recursive_merge(h1, h2)
puts h1
```

This method results the follwing output.
Please note that this method overwrites h1 itself.

```
{"students"=>[{"name"=>"bobby", "hobbies"=>[{"outdoor"=>"cycling", "indoor"=>"reading"}]}]}
```